# prediction error using SVM in R

Tags: r, svm, prediction

I used SVM function in package "e1071",

The first problem is when i try to predict number of rows less than rows I trained it gives me the following error:

```
td = wholeData[1:10000,]
model <- svm(Type~.,data = td,type="C-classification")
x =wholeData[1:5000,]
p=predict(model,x)
```

> Error in newdata[, object$scaled, drop = FALSE] : 
>          (subscript) logical subscript too long

---

The second problem is when I try to use huge number of rows it gives the following message:
"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.6 Gb"
I do not know to overcome this problem.

```
td=wholeData[1:100000,]
model1=svm(Type~.,data = td)
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.6 Gb
>        In addition: Warning messages:
>        1: In model.matrix.default(Terms, m) :
>          Reached total allocation of 5849Mb: see help(memory.size)
>        2: In model.matrix.default(Terms, m) :
>          Reached total allocation of 5849Mb: see help(memory.size)
>        3: In model.matrix.default(Terms, m) :
>          Reached total allocation of 5849Mb: see help(memory.size)
>        4: In model.matrix.default(Terms, m) :
>          Reached total allocation of 5849Mb: see help(memory.size)

The structure of data as follow

```
str(wholeData)
'data.frame':   550116 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Text   : chr  "IL-2" "gene" "expression" "and" ...
 $ wLength: int  4 4 10 3 8 1 10 7 4 8 ...
 $ Cap    : int  1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Digit  : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ POS    : int  11 20 20 9 21 21 20 14 11 40 ...
 $ Type   : Factor w/ 11 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 8 11 11 4 9 11 11 4 11 ...
 $ idf    : num  3.2 1.7 1.53 1.01 2.96 2.13 1.73 2.63 4.89 3.94 ...
 $ isword : int  0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 ...
```

Comment: The only way to really overcome the vector allocation error is to get more memory. Unless you can make it sparse.

Comment: Ok i will try. Thanks

Comment: You might need *a lot* more memory; and also a lot of patience. In my experience, SVMs are mainly of academic, educational purpose. The computational costs of SVMs scale approximately with O(N^3). Therefore I consider them as practically useless for real-life applications.

Comment: SVMs may be useful if one manages to significantly reduce the size of the data without losing essential information, for instance by applying sophisticated downsampling techniques or by repeatedly training the model using different, small subsets. In the case of an unfiltered, large set of data there are much more efficient ML algorithms.